# C++ String Comperison - Why Brute Force alg, works faster than my Knuth–Morris–Pratt alg - I know there must a mistake but I don't know were

Tags: c++, string-comparison, knuth-morris-pratt

I implemented Brute Force alg and Knuth–Morris–Pratt alg and checked how much time it takes for them to complete the task. For a sample of data that I provided it took BF alg 2 seconds to finnish and for the KMP it was 12 seconds. Gap didn't change for other random text samples so there must by some sort of a mistake, cause the difference is to big plus KMP should be faster than BF, no slower.

Brute Force

```
    bool Does_full_pattern_match(const string& full_tekst, const string& pattern, const int& index_of_first_match)
    {
        if (full_tekst != "" && pattern != "" && index_of_first_match >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)pattern.length(); i++)
            {
                if (pattern[i] != full_tekst[index_of_first_match + i]) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    int* Brute_Force_Approach_returns_table_of_index(const string& full_tekst, const string& pattern, int& size)
    {
        if (pattern != "")
        {
            Queue<int> obj;
                        

            int length = full_tekst.length();

            
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if ((full_tekst[i] == pattern[0]) && Does_full_pattern_match(full_tekst, pattern, i))
                {                   
                    obj.Enque(i);
                }
            }       


            return obj.Return_Tab(size);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
```

Knuth - Morris - Pratt

Don't mind the Queue obj, and the Morrisa_Pratta_Tab_Generator function. I checked it so many times and it works as should. The queue is there out of convenience and it's also definitely not the source of a mistake.

```
int Return_Index_Of_Missmatch(const string& full_tekst, const string& pattern, const int& limit, const int& pattern_size, const int& index_in_tekst)
    {
        if (full_tekst == "" || pattern == "" || index_in_tekst < 0) return -2;
        else
        {       

            for (int i = 0; i < pattern_size && index_in_tekst + i < limit; i++)
            {
                if (pattern[i] != full_tekst[index_in_tekst + i]) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
    int* KMP(const string& full_tekst, const string& pattern, int& size_of_returned_tab)
    {
        
        int length = (int)full_tekst.length();
        int pattern_size = (int)pattern.length();
            

        int size = 0;
        int* prefix_table = Morrisa_Pratta_Tab_Generator(pattern, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) prefix_table[i]++;   
        

        Queue<int> found_match_index;
        
        int result;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; )
        {
            result = Return_Index_Of_Missmatch(full_tekst, pattern, length, pattern_size, i);

            if (0 <= result)
            {
                i += prefix_table[result];
            }
            else if (result == -1) // found match
            {
                found_match_index.Enque(i);
                i += pattern_size;
            }
        }
        
        return found_match_index.Return_Tab(size_of_returned_tab);
    }
```

If you have any comments on my code or you know what causes this behaviour, I would be more than happy to read your comment

I did some changes, but none of them made a significant change. The code above is the final product and I don't know what causes it to run so slow

Comment: Formatting here is a bit of a wreck. The `{}` button can usually fix it.

Comment: 1) There is no `main` program.  2) There is no test data.  3) You failed to mention compiler and compiler flags (optimization) used to build the application.  If you are running an unoptimized or "debug" build, then the timings are meaningless.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including the data the code was timed on.

Comment: Unrelated: `return obj.Return_Tab(size);` kinda creeps me out. Make damn sure that the table the returned pointer's pointing at is still valid after `obj`'s lifetime expires.

Comment: I haven't eyeballed your code at all, but modern CPU's like processing data sequentially (because it makes best use of the cache) and that could be a factor here.

Comment: It looks like your brute force method only compares the first character of the pattern, of course it's going to be fast. Won't work though.

Comment: Note: For really big strings the casting in `for (int i = 0; i < (int)pattern.length(); i++)` may result in horrific failure. `for (size_t i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++)` is a safer option.

Comment: Not your question, but when you found pattern you do `i += pattern_size;`, what is wrong in general. You need to shift in accordance to the calculated prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Alright guys, I learned something today. I didn't realize how different Debug_Mode was from Release, I thought that it basically makes the whole thing slower, but the proportions of time performance of each task would be more or less the same. But when I switched to Release the situation turned upside down and now the KMP is a little bit faster than Brute Force, as it should be.

Turn out the algorithm is fine and the fact that I used to run it on Debug_Mode made the difference.

Thanks for the comments and potential solutions

Comment: Your implementation might seem to work, but it has the bug I mentioned above and it has some other flaws in the way how you treat the indices of the prefix. So it more or less degenerates to some kind of slightly improved brute force but is still far away from the full performance of a naive KMP implementation.